# elasticsearch aggregation result is 0

Tags: elasticsearch

The following is my query for elasticsearch:

```
GET index/_search
{
   "size": 0,
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
            "and": [
               {
                  "term": {
                     "id_1": "xx"
                  }
               },
               {
                  "term": {
                     "level": "level2"
                  }
               },
               {
                  "or": [
                     {
                        "term": {
                           "type": "yyy"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "term": {
                           "type": "zzzz"
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "variable": {
         "stats": {
            "field": "score"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

But the agg result is as follows:

```
{
   "took": 2,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 68,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
      "variable": {
         "count": 30,
         "min": 0,
         "max": 0,
         "avg": 0,
         "sum": 0
      }
   }
}
```

Why the min,max etc are 0. But value is there for score like(0.18,0.25,etc..). Also in mapping the type for score is long. Please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Edit:

value in index:

```
"score": 0.18
```

Single document:

```
{
            "_index": "index",
            "_type": "ppppp",
            "_id": "n0IiTEd2QFCnJUZOSiNu1w",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "name_2": "aaa",
               "keyid": "bbbb",
               "qqq": "cccc",
               "level": "level2",
               "type": "kkk",
               "keytype": "Year",
               "org_id": 25,
               "tempid": "113",
               "id_2": "561",
               "name_1": "xxxxx",
               "date_obj": [
                  {
                     "keyid": "wwwww",
                     "keytype": "Year",
                     "value": 21.510617952000004,
                     "date": "2015",
                     "id": "ggggggg",
                     "productid": ""
                  },
                  {
                     "keyid": "rrrrrr",
                     "keytype": "Year",
                     "value": 0.13,
                     "date": "2015",
                     "id": "iiiiii",
                     "productid": ""
                  }
               ],
               "date": "2015",
               "ddddd": 21.510617952000004,
               "id_1": "29",
               "leveltype": "nnnn",
               "tttt": 0.13,
               "score": 0.13    ------------------->problem           
            }
         }
```

Mapping:

```
curl -XPUT ip:9200/index -d '{   
    "mappings" : {
        "places" : {            
            "properties" : {
                "score" : { "type" : "float"}                
            }
        }
}
}'
```

Comment: Are you sure you indexed the `score` fields with a `long` value (i.e. `0.18`) and not with a `string` value (i.e. `"0.18"`)? Can you add `"size": 1` to you query so we can see a sample document?

Comment: @Val please see my edited post.

Comment: It's weird because in the response the aggregation should be called `variavle` and not `score`... Have you mistyped anything? Unlucky copy/paste?

Comment: @Val i mistyped. Now u see my edited post..

Comment: please add your index mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix should be as simple as changing the type of the `score` field to `float` (or `double`) instead of `long`. `long` is an integer type and 0.18 will be indexed as 0 under the hood.

```
"score" : {
    "type" : "float",
    "null_value" : 0.0
}
```

Note that you'll need to reindex your data after making the mapping change.

Comment: Maybe the first document you indexed had a score 1 or 2 or 3. Is that possible? When I index a document with `score: 0.18` on a brand new index, the `score` field gets created as `double` type, so you must have been in an unlucky case of having a integer score in your first document.

Comment: Did you wipe the index and recreate it from scratch?

Comment: Please edit the question with the mapping you're using.

Comment: Now I see the `score` field has a space at the beginning (i.e. `" score"`). Typo or not? All these little things make a difference.

Comment: What module/package/plugin are you using to fetch data from MongoDB and index it into ES?

Comment: Can you please clear some more doubts?? Is it possible to create mapping for generic variable as follows curl -XPUT ip:9200/index -d '{   
    "mappings" : {
        "places" : {            
            "properties" : {
                "sco*" : { "type" : "float"}                
            }
        }
}
}' so any variable starts with sco should have type float

Comment: This should be another question actually. But the short answer is yes using [dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-root-object-type.html#_dynamic_templates). Also you should accept answers if they helped you solve your problem. That'll also help future users.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85278/discussion-between-val-and-subburaj).